# Solution for automatic VPN-Connection on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, bash, vpn, openvpn

I am searching since ages for a solution to connect to VPN-Servers automatically in my Ubuntu 13.10. It should connect on startup and reconnect on connection-drop. I tried several things:

- VPNAutoconnect sourceforge.net/projects/vpnautoconnect/ but it doesn't work and has like no documentation
- Bash-Script like what I found here ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1756831

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  while [ "true" ]
  do
  vpnck=$(nmcli con status uuid 2df5dab5-21da-66fa-927e-bd754cdf4656)
  if [ $vpnck = TorGuard.Germany.UDP ]; then
    sleep 20
  else 
    sleep 1s && nmcli con up uuid 2df5dab5-21da-66fa-927e-bd754cdf4656
  fi
  sleep 20
  done
  ```

  but this starts reconnecting my VPN-connection every 20 seconds. Sorry I don't know bash-scripting.
- there is a nice little program from TorGuard - [Download](https://torguard.net/downloads/TorGuard_unix_4_1_3.sh.zip). Unfortunately it is not working with startup and more unfortunately is that it requires rootrights.
- and I found this entry on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328823/vpn-autoconnect)

but all these solutions I tried out are not really satisfactory. Has anyone a good idea e.g. how to improve the bash-script?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I got it...
in Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander you can now go to the Network Manager -> Edit Connections -> Edit your Connection -> General. Here you can now activate the option to automatically connect.